# Error 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1. Can't find unmatching columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I keep getting this error when I try to build this little database:

```
ERROR: Error 1136: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
SQL Code:
        INSERT INTO area (name, description)
        VALUES  ('National'),
                ('The place for all National political issues.')

SQL script execution finished: statements: 19 succeeded, 1 failed
```

It seems like all of my column counts match so I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I think the problem is happening with my inserts. I'm using MySQLWorkbench and the problem happens each time I try to build the database from scratch. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you.

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema RvB
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema RvB
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `RvB` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `RvB` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`area`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`area` (
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`links`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`links` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `link` VARCHAR(999) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`affiliation`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`affiliation` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `affiliation` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`privilege`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`privilege` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `privilege` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`pages`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`pages` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `area` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `area_idx` (`area` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `area`
    FOREIGN KEY (`area`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`area` (`name`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`accounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`accounts` (
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `party` INT NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` DATE NULL,
  `privileges` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`),
  INDEX `party_idx` (`party` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `privileges_idx` (`privileges` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `party`
    FOREIGN KEY (`party`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`affiliation` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `privileges`
    FOREIGN KEY (`privileges`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`privilege` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`posts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`posts` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `affiliation` INT NOT NULL,
  `post_text` VARCHAR(9999) NULL,
  `time_and_date` DATETIME(4) NOT NULL,
  `votes` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `page` INT NOT NULL,
  `post_title` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `page_idx` (`page` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `affiliation_idx` (`affiliation` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `username_idx` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `page`
    FOREIGN KEY (`page`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`pages` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `affiliation`
    FOREIGN KEY (`affiliation`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`affiliation` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `username`
    FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`accounts` (`username`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`postComments`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`postComments` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  `text` VARCHAR(8000) NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `post_id_idx` (`post_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `username_idx` (`username` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `postid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`posts` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user-name`
    FOREIGN KEY (`username`)
    REFERENCES `RvB`.`accounts` (`username`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `RvB`.`contactUs`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `RvB`.`contactUs` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
  `message` VARCHAR(2000) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
-- begin attached script 'script'
INSERT INTO privilege (privilege)
VALUES  ('reg_user'),
        ('moderator'),
        ('archmoderator'),
        ('admin');


INSERT INTO affiliation (affiliation)
VALUES  ('republican'),
        ('democrat'),
        ('libertarian'),
        ('green'),
        ('constitution');

INSERT INTO area (name, description)
VALUES  ('National'),
        ('The place for all National political issues.');

INSERT INTO area (name, description)
VALUES  ('Colorado'),
        ('The place for all Colorado issues or politicians.');

INSERT INTO pages (title, area)
VALUES  ('Abortion'),
        ('National');

INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, party, password, creation_date, privileges)
VALUES  ('dan_the_repub'),
        ('republican@gmail.com'),
        ('1'),
        ('password'),
        ('2020-09-14'),
        ('1');

INSERT INTO accounts (username, email, party, password, creation_date, privileges)
VALUES  ('kendra_the_demo'),
        ('democratsRus@gmail.com'),
        ('2'),
        ('password'),
        ('2020-09-13'),
        ('1');

INSERT INTO posts (username, affiliation, post_text, time_and_date, votes, page, post_title)
VALUES  ('dan_the_repub'),
        ('1'),
        ('Republicans rule!!'),
        ('2020-09-15 12:43:10'),
        ('20'),
        ('1'),
        ('What I think about Republicans, a statement');

INSERT INTO posts (username, affiliation, post_text, time_and_date, votes, page, post_title)
VALUES  ('kendra_the_demo'),
        ('2'),
        ('Go go go go Democrats!!'),
        ('2020-09-13 11:42:05'),
        ('25'),
        ('1'),
        ('Democrats are the best! Everyone else stinks!');
-- end attached script 'script'
```

Comment: For heavans sakes, there is a manual you know. `VALUES  ('National', 'The place for all National political issues.')`

Comment: You have 2 columns specifically mentioned `(name, description)` but are only passing a single value `('National')`

Comment: You need brakets after VALUES like **INSERT INTO area (name, description)
VALUES  ('National', 'The place for all National political issues.');**

Answer (score 0):

Each parenthesized group after `VALUES` is a single row, with an expression for each column in it. If you want to insert 1 row with 2 columns, you should just have a single group.

```
VALUES ('National', 'The place for all National political issues.')
```

Your code is trying to insert 2 rows, but it's only supplying a value for 1 column in each row. The number of expressions in each group has to match the number of columns in the list after `INSERT INTO area`.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!